Authorized image src embedded in a markdown component in angular app
I have this issue with an angular application I'm creating, I have a markdown component and a a feature to upload images and attach it to the markdown content with an image tag.
<img src="http://whatever.com?filename=myimage.jpg"/>

The problem is that the API endpoint that respond with the image needs to be authenticated like the rest of the application so the image can only see by the users logged in.
I tried interceptors but of course I don't think that will work basically because it is out of the Angular Http Client request.
Open for some ideas here, thanks
****** Edit *****
Based on @JSON Derulo response, I tried that (the pipe to add the authorization) and it didn't worked, the thing is this, once the markdown content is saved in the database the content is showed in the page using the markdown component: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-markdown so basically if I put the pipe you suggested the markdown component don't show the image just the text

What kind of authentication does the endpoint have ?

'Authorization': 'Bearer <token>' header

Is it your own API? Can you handle it?

Yes, I can but I cannot remove auth.
